# Sitecore.Context.PageMode.IsPageEditor VS Sitecore.Context.PageMode.IsExperienceEditor

Tags: sitecore, sitecore-mvc, sitecore8.1

Inside a rendering, I have some code like this:

```cs
 @if (!Model.Item.IsFieldEmpty(ContentBlock.Title) || Sitecore.Context.PageMode.IsPageEditor)
    {
        <h2>
            @Html.Sitecore().RenderField(ContentBlock.Title, Model.Item)
        </h2>
    }
```

It still works fine for me. But i am getting an warning like **'Sitecore.Context.PageMode.IsPageEditor' is obsolete : use IsExperienceEditor instead.** What's the ***difference*** between them ??

***Note:*** currently i am using sitecore 8.1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PageEditor is the named used pre Sitecore 8 - they changed it to Experience Editor. So it is the same thing, but the old name is deprecated and might be removed in newer versions.

Comment: Via ILSpy:
 [System.Obsolete("Use IsExperienceEditor instead.")]
 public static bool IsPageEditor
 {
  get
  {
   return Context.PageMode.IsExperienceEditor;
  }
 }

Comment: Is it all about renaming??

Comment: yes - It's based on the new main focus from Sitecore, which is "experience". Thats also why Email Campaign Manager, have changed name to Email Experience Manager.

Answer (score 0):

The différence only in name convention, Page Editor has a new name in Sitecore 8 = Experience Editor.

I strongly recoment you use new name.